# ddclient: do not update IPv4, but just IPv6

Tags: ubuntu, dyndns, ddclient

I'm using dydns to name my servers. My provider is using [CGN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT), therefore my IPv4 is almost useless. Updating my IPv4 does not make any sense and I want to skip/deactivate this, I just want to update my IPv6 (e.g. after a prefix update). Is there a way to achieve/configure this with ddclient?

Comment: If your ISP is using CGN, then you have a residential network, and your residential terms of service forbid running services to the public Internet. You need to get a business account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a sufficiently new [Perl ddclient](https://github.com/ddclient/ddclient/blob/develop/ddclient.in)  perhaps

```
use=if
ipv6=yes
ipv4=no
```

Makes use of the OS interface command to find IPs, ip on Linux, others on other platforms.

My reading of the source is that it only does one address family, I think. Disabled v4 just in case.  Per the [template config file](https://github.com/ddclient/ddclient/blob/develop/ddclient.conf.in), IPv6 requires newer than 3.8.1.

---

Or, consider using a v6 only network for some hosts. Remove all (non-loopback) v4 addresses  from interfaces.  Implement transition methods like DNS64/NAT64 where required to connect to IPv4 hosts.

Comment: `usev6=ip` yields `DEBUG: get_ipv6: using ip, ip reports <undefined>`. I tried `usev6=web, web=checkipv6.dyndns.com, web-skip='IP Address'` and the website shows the correct IPv6, but the debug output says `DEBUG: get_ipv6: using web, checkipv6.dyndns.com reports <undefined>` .

Comment: My mistake, ip method is static IP, as in command line option.  if is probably what you want, if getting the IP of a Linux box.  See edit.

Comment: With a tiny modification to `usev6=if, if=enx...` the edit fixed it for me. Thank you.